# Pass specific $attrs parameter to Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have the following code in my parent component:

```
<TestVIsComponent :post="somepost" :somevalue="17" data-status="activated" data-feature="new" @change="submitChange"></TestVIsComponent>
```

And the following child component:

```
  <div>
     <h1 v-bind="$attrs">{{post.id}}</h1>
  </div>
```

This code and the $attrs would pass the data-status="activated" data-feature="new" attributes to the H1 tag instead of the div which is the desired result. Here is the result:

```
<h1 data-status="activated" data-feature="new">1</h1>
```

However, is there a way to pass only one attribute to the H1 tag? Is there a way to somehow iterate the $attrs in the child? Something like attrs[0] or attrs['attribute_name']? I need to achieve the following or similar:

```
  <div>
     <h1 v-bind="$attrs[0]">{{post.id}}</h1>
     <h3 v-bind="$attrs[1]">{{post.something}}</h3>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what attributes are for `div` element then you should use them as `props` instead of `$attrs`.

or you can split `$attrs`

```js
<template>
<div v-bind="divAttrs">
   <h1 v-bind="h1Attrs">{{post.id}}</h1>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   computed: {
     divAttrs () {
       const allowed = ['data-status', 'data-feature']
       return Object.keys(this.$attrs)
         .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
         .reduce((obj, key) => {
           obj[key] = this.$attrs[key]
           return obj
         }, {})
     },
     h1Attrs () {
       const notAllowed = ['data-status', 'data-feature']
       return Object.keys(this.$attrs)
         .filter(key => !notAllowed.includes(key))
         .reduce((obj, key) => {
           obj[key] = this.$attrs[key]
           return obj
         }, {})
     }
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it is working. However is there a simpler solution for iterating or another option? Also, I found that I can pass the attributes to a data parameter:

data(){
    return {
      myAttr: this.$attrs
    }
  }

Then I can use it as {{myAttr["data-status"]}}. 


Is this recommended or should I avoid assigning it?

Comment: It is a general solution and you can easily change `allowed` variable to control these getters. you don't need to assign `$attrs` into data parameter if you don't want to use reactivity. just use it as `{{ $attrs['data-status'] }}`